# What does the Target parameter in Hyperlinks.Add() do? How to use it?

Tags: .net, hyperlink, ms-word, vsto

Creating a VSTO add-in for MS Word, I can programmatically add hyperlinks to a document via [`Hyperlinks.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.hyperlinks.add?view=word-pia).

Unfortunately, the description of the `Target` parameter tells me little or nothing:

> Optional Object. The name of the frame or window in which you want to load the specified hyperlink.

So what is it actually good for? Can I use it to open a URI with another application than the default one (e.g. the browser for links)? Or can I open a `Form` from my project? Or something completely different...?

I tried passing strings like `"Firefox"` or `"Chrome"`, but it tells me

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   HResult=0x800A1018
>   Message=Bad Parameter.

What kind of object can I pass there? If a string, how to format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the parameters for `Hyperlinks.Add` come from HTML (logically, since a hyperlink is of HTML-origin). As the language reference says

> The name of the frame or window in which you want to load the
>   specified hyperlink.

This would be the "label" of a named window or frame on the webpage to which the link points. `Target` is also a hyperlink attribute in the HTML language. A small example of such HTML that illustrates what `Target` is used for:

Pseudo Webpage:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE></HEAD>
  <FRAMESET>
     <FRAME NAME="win-left" SRC="start.html">
     <FRAME NAME="win-right" SRC="next.html">
  </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

Hyperlink in `next.html` that opens `xyz.html` in the left frame:

```
<A HREF="xyz.html" TARGET="win-left">Text of hyperlink</A>
```